# K means clustering for time series data

Tags: clustering, k-means

Suppose, we have three metrics (M1,M2,M3) for one database D1 which have time series data and similarly same metric (M1,M2,M3) for other database D2 and so on.How do we cluster using K- means clustering on what dimension?

sample time series data of metrics  M1 -- (43 value at 12 am,23 at 1 am, 78.5 at 2am ...6values)

similarly of metrics  M2 -- (41 value at 12 am,21.3 at 1 am, 58 at 2am ...6values)

Comment: Can you explain better the data? Maybe add a simple numeric example, thanks.